# How to make a custom Django api

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I made a simple Django website which supports user authentication(login/Logoff) and Registration I want to make a custom API which does this using REST how would i do this

Comment: I do not know where to start..i am asking someone to guide me

Comment: google is your friend and so is the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/topics)

Comment: Use Django REST framework: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to learn how to create REST API in Django, Here we cannot write the whole code for your requirement but can give you suggestion as per your question.

as @Siegmeyer said in comment that you should use the Django Rest Framework which is best and have tutorials and examples too:

**Strongly Re-commanded to use:**
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

*Read blog with link below for step by step tutorial:*
http://agiliq.com/blog/2014/12/building-a-restful-api-with-django-rest-framework

*For video check link below:*
https://godjango.com/41-start-your-api-django-rest-framework-part-1/

or try youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/results?q=rest+api+in+django+rest+framework

These may help you crate your API in Django.

Comment: DRF (django rest framework) works out of the box only for ORM resources (models). If anyone returns data that are created on the fly uppon each request, I would recommend tastypie or custom urls/views coding

Comment: In my experience, DRF was better for custom cases as well. using APIView or simple functions we can create custom request/ response structure and integrate DRF features like permissions, authentication etc. I would recommend DRF over any other package or fully custom views.